# insert entire content of a text file in the position of single line using command line linux

Tags: bash, command-line, sed, str-replace

I am bascially trying to replace a single line of text with the entire content of another text file from the command line (linux). Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Care to add the data?

Comment: If you use python, the solution is very graceful: https://gist.github.com/nicky-zs/6bc90122feb6d490df36

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed -e '/trigger/r newfile' -e '/trigger/d' org_file
```

Here,

`newfile` will have a content a content to be insert when `trigger` is found in `org_file`.

**Test:**

```
$ cat > org_file
line 1
line 2
line 3
trigger
line 6
line 7
$ cat > newfile
line 4
line 5
$ sed -e '/trigger/r newfile' -e '/trigger/d' org_file 
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[NR]=$0;f++;next} /trigger/ {for (i=1;i<=f;i++) print a[i];next}1'  newdata orgfile
```

It stores the `newdata` in an array `a`
When `trigger` is found in `orgfile`, replace it by all data from array `a`

If you need to change a line and know the line number change `/trigger/` to `FNR==20`

Answer (score 0):

A variant of sat's answer with `sed`, which does not need to read `org_file.txt` twice:

```
sed '/trigger/{
         r newfile.txt
         d
     }' org_file.txt
```

Or with fewer line breaks:

```
sed '/trigger/{r newfile.txt
  d}' file.txt
```

There's a drawback: it's not a one-liner, as `r` commands interprets everything after it as a filename (more details [here](https://superuser.com/questions/456246/sed-weirdness-unmatched)).
A workaround was provided by Peter.O (see above link):

```
sed -f <(sed 's/\\n/\n/'<<<'/trigger/{r new_file.txt\nd}') org_file.txt
```